# How can i let my players withdraw BNB tokens from my NFT game

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance, bsc

I am developing a NFT Game that will work with BNB in the Binance Smart Chain.

Players can already deposit BNB by sending a transaction to my Wallet. But how could it be reversed?

How can the user with a button ask BNB to my wallet from his MetaMask wallet?

Im using Unity to create the game using the https://chainsafe.github.io/game-docs/ API.

Like this:
[Example of NFT game wallet giving tokens to user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiwX3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if the bnb are inside a wallet you should find a way for the users to create and off chain petition and then using the private keys of the wallet you can create some automate script to transfer the bnb to the address of the user, but you should fund the wallet to pay the gas fees